# Ask for client side confirmation when a DevExpress ASPxCheckBox changes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, devexpress

I'm trying to add a confirmation dialog to have the user confirm changes to the checked status of an ASPxCheckBox.

**Take 1**
Based on [this DevExpress support center question](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q355682) I'm trying the following code:

```xml
<dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox1" runat="server">
    <ClientSideEvents CheckedChanged="ConfirmChange" />
</dx:ASPxCheckBox>
```

With this JavaScript:

```
function ConfirmChange (s, e) {
    console.log(s);
    console.log(e);
    return false; // For testing
    // return confirm(); // Should become this
}
```

I was hoping/expecting the `return false` bit to prevent the change, but it happens nonetheless. I've gone through the console logged parameters to see if I can affect anything there, but doesn't look like it. I've also read the [`CheckedChanged` DevExpress documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientCheckBox_CheckedChangedtopic) but it holds no clue to my purpose either.

**Take 2**
I've also tried doing this in code behind:

```
var checkbox = (ASPxCheckBox)myGridView.FindEditRowCellTemplateControl(myCol, "ASPxCheckBox1";
checkbox.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('You sure?')")
```

This also pops up the confirm dialog, which fails to prevent a change if cancel is clicked.

**Take 3**
Finally, based a suggestion in one of the early answers here, I've also tried going the validation route:

```xml
<dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox1" runat="server">
    <ClientSideEvents Validation="ConfirmChange" />
</dx:ASPxCheckBox>
```

JavaScript:

```
function ConfirmChange (s, e) {
    e.isValid = confirm();
}
```

However, this doesn't *prevent* or *revert* the change, but presents a validation error if you hit cancel in the confirm dialog.

**So, bottom line**
How can I inject a client side confirmation dialog before the `ASPxCheckBox`'s change happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prevent the change in `ASPxClientCheckBox.CheckedChanged` event because this event occurs on the client side when the editor's checked state **is changed**. You can revert value by using [`ASPxClientCheckBox.GetChecked`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientCheckBox_GetCheckedtopic) method and [`ASPxClientCheckBox.SetChecked`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientCheckBox_SetCheckedtopic) method.
Here is example:

```
<dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox1" runat="server">
    <ClientSideEvents CheckedChanged="ConfirmChange" />
</dx:ASPxCheckBox>
```

JavaScript:

```
function ConfirmChange (s, e) {
    console.log(s);
    console.log(e);

    //Save the checked state
    value = s.GetChecked();

    //Revert changes immediately
    s.SetChecked(!s.GetChecked());

    result = false; // For testing
    // result = confirm(); // Should become this

    if (result) {s.SetChecked(value);}
}
```

Comment: This is getting close. However, it does not *prevent* or *revert* the checked status change, instead shows a validation error "(!) Invalid value" next to the checkbox if I press cancel.

Comment: @Jeroen I have found another way by using `GetChecked` and `SetChecked` methods. I have updated my answer.

Comment: It's a shame that it does visually *revert* the checked status instead of (what I would've preferred) *prevent* the change, but I guess with DevExpress you don't have the luxury of minding such details. Thanks again though!

Comment: @Jeroen I have updated my answer. You can try to save the checked state, revert changes immediately, take a confirm from user and update checked state.

Comment: Wow! I guess you *do* have the luxury, you just need to know what hoops to jump through. I'd give another +1 if I could've :)